# MongoDB documents are randomly deleted after a few hours

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I own a vps. There we have three minecraft servers and one discord bot. we also have a local mongoDB running on the vps. I have connected to it using node.js mongoose library. I am talking about the discord bot in this case. When I create documents in the mongodb, it works, and the code reads everything. Suddenly, after about 2-3 hours, every single document i created, is deleted. Its really annoying, and makes the bot completely useless. There are no errors, no logs, it just deletes them. When hosting the mongodb publicly, everything works, and nothing is getting deleted, so its not the code. There are no TTL indexes as far as I know, but I couldn't find any reliable documentation on how to check using mongoose.

I am just trying to host my bot on a VPS, its my first time doing so. Because we want to avoid dataleaks, we decided to host the mongoDB locally on the VPS, we need the mongoDB to communicate over all the servers (minecraft and discord). Since everything works, and nothing is being deleted when hosting the mongoDB using atlas, I would think hosting it on the VPS would work. When we tried contacting the support team on the VPS service, they said they couldn't do anything as this is a problem with mongoDB

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My first guess would also be TTL index. You can try to follow [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) to see if that is the root cause. Unfortunately, for your current information provided, I don't think anyone can provide any further help.

Comment: What information would you like me to provide?

Comment: I'm 99,9% confident that is unrelated to mongo, you should analyze logic you have or provide more details like repro, mongo configuration and etc

Comment: dododo, but everything works perfectly when ruinning it on the atlas

Answer (score 0):

There is a TTL index defined on your collection. Or one of your friends is messing with you.

Here are some very easy to implement idea's in order to check:

1. Just get the index list using `getIndexes`

```
const indexes = await Model.collection.getIndexes({full: true});
// check the output
```

2. Change the collection name in the mongoose schema, if there's a pre-existing TTL index then creating a new collection by changing the name of the schema will ensure it not used, if after this change everything works you can be sure that was the issue.
3. Make sure your code doesn't create a TTL index, like code looks like:

```
Model.index({ "created_at": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
```

I'm sure once you check these points your problem will be resolved.

Comment: After using the getIndexes method on one of the models, this was the output: 
`[ { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' } ]` 
There are no TTL indexes. There are no logs either. Its weird, because running a public db on the VPS works perfectly, but once we switch to a local one, it is just being randomly deleted. I know its not my friend, as he is equally as fustrated as me.

Comment: Where is this "local" db? any chance u have a script that clears the db on that machine?

Comment: Well its pretty much just a database running on the vps. there shouldnt be a script because it doesnt remove the other documents on minecraft servers running on the vps